# Read colons for an URL adress with hibernate

Tags: java, windows, hibernate

Well, I know there's a lot of stuff regarding to this issue, but I couldn't find an specific one that helps me with my problem. Or, at least, I didn't figure out it yet :/.

My issue is the folowing: I have a database with products, each of them with an image field that corresponds to an URL to that image.

Then, when I wanna make the query to get the url image, which starts with 'http://' or 'https://', I get the classic colon trouble due to hibernate behavior.

The big deal of this is that ubuntu and mac don't have ptoblems if that prefix is not present... but windows does.

That's my problem... if there's a way to fix the colons problem, or maybe to avoid the prefix on windows so it can load the images, I'll be the happiest man on Earth. I'm sorry, but I really don't know what to do to solve this, or if there's even an alternative that allows me not to deal with this specific problem.

Thank you in advance for your time, people! :)

I'm doin' a native query:

`[UPDATE products SET products.title = 'On Cloudsurfer Running Women\'s Shoes Size 5.5', products.brand = 'On Running', products.urlImage = 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31NpvJwpEYL.SL75.jpg', products.weight = 1.85, products.width = 7.8, products.height = 4.2, products.length = 10.9, products.amazonSize = '5.5 B(M) Women\'s US' WHERE products.sku='0000027001WM-SZ-5.5';]`

And my problem is with the colons... on ubuntu and mac, the prefix is not a problem, but it seems that windows needs it all the time, 'cause the images are not showing on windows.

**ERRATA**: sorry people! Please forget the fact that only windows don't show the pictures. The system is huge, and I forgot that I patched the ":" with "\". That's the reason ubuntu and mac shows the images but windows doesn't...

Anyway, the colons issue is still a problem :(

Comment: What kind of query are you running? And what are you doing with the image URL? I can't see what the OS has to do with a Hibernate query.

Comment: OS has nothing to with this hibernate query or your URL column in Database. Post your entity and post your HQLQuery. Theory questions cant help any.

Comment: I'm doin' a native query:
 
<code>
[UPDATE products SET products.title = 'On Cloudsurfer Running Women\'s Shoes Size 5.5', products.brand = 'On Running', products.urlImage = '"http://"ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31NpvJwpEYL._SL75_.jpg', products.weight = 1.85, products.width = 7.8, products.height = 4.2, products.length = 10.9, products.amazonSize = '5.5 B(M) Women\'s US' WHERE products.sku='0000027001WM-SZ-5.5';]
And my problem is with the colons... on ubuntu and mac, the prefix is not a problem, but it seems that windows needs it all the time, 'cause the images are not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes persistent objects may contain fields with characters like %, _, !, and so on. One issue with this arises in case one is using Hibernate’s criteria queries for filtering.

Use this code snipet for the reference:

```
public class EscapedRestrictions {
    public static Criterion ilike(String propertyName, String value) {
        return new EscapedILikeExpression(propertyName, value);
    }

    public static Criterion ilike(String propertyName, String value, MatchMode matchMode) {
        return new EscapedILikeExpression(propertyName, value, matchMode);
    }
}

class EscapedILikeExpression extends IlikeExpression {
    private static final String HIBERNATE_ESCAPE_CHAR = "\\";

    public EscapedILikeExpression(String propertyName, Object value) {
        super(propertyName, value);
    }

    public EscapedILikeExpression(String propertyName, String value, MatchMode matchMode) {
        super(propertyName, replaceAll(value), matchMode);
    }

    private static String replaceAll(String value) {
        return value
                .replace("\\",  HIBERNATE_ESCAPE_CHAR + "\\")
                .replace("_",   HIBERNATE_ESCAPE_CHAR + "_")
                .replace("%",   HIBERNATE_ESCAPE_CHAR + "%");

    }
}
```

The usage is the same as in the snippet above, with only difference of replacing Restrictions class with EscapedRestrictions.